# how to set image URL as absolute physical path?

Tags: c#, asp.net, relative-path, imageurl

i have  image-button control in a grid view my customer need to enter a path of folder in another page i stored this path in database i need because customer store images in external hard cannot transfer image from hard disk to website images because it has a huge size

my image table contain image-name  when user display grid-view i concatenate image-name from database and path from database also how can i do that

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="photo">
           <ItemTemplate >


               <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# GetImagePath()+Eval("ImageName")  %>'  Width="100px" Height="100px" Style="cursor: pointer" OnClientClick = "return LoadDiv(this.src);" /> 
           </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: What does `GetImagePath()` return?

Comment: dont forget to upvote and mark it as accepted if it worked for you ...

Answer (score 2):

you need write down in you function like this

```
public string GetImage(string name)
{
  string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(("~/Admin/Images/" , name)); 
  return path;
}
```

or

you can also do like this

```
void GrdVw_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Image rowImage = (Image) e.Row.FindControl("currentDocFile");
        rowImage.ImageUrl = whatever;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks 4 replay but i ask can i set ImageUrl as
ImageUrl="D:/images/1.jpg"

Comment: @user1637402 - not possible ..you need to put image in the virtual directory ..you cannot refer direcly from hard drive

Comment: Pranay shouldn't you use the Combine method when using the Server.MapPath method..?

Comment: @Pranay Rana sure from that?

Comment: @Pranay Rana ok thanks there is no solution 4 that data except transfer it inside application root

Comment: @PranayRana I think the line "string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(("~/Admin/Images/" , name));" should read "string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(("~/Admin/Images/"), name);"

Comment: @user1637402 Visitors to a website need to be able to access a resource from a location that is accessible to their client (i.e. the web browser on their computer) and not one solely accessible from the server. The path "D:/images/1.jpg" would only work if their computer had a drive mapped as D: containing a directory named images with a file named 1.jpg - and it would show THEIR image on the page and not yours. Either map D:\images\ as a virtual directory in IIS (e.g. to yoursite.com/images/) as Pranay suggested or use URL rewriting (available in IIS7+) to serve the files from the drive.

Comment: @user1637402 Additionally, consider the implications of serving images so large you cannot copy them to your server across the internet. Many users will not have fast connections. It is rare to have a genuine reason images should be any larger than a few hundred kilobytes. If the image is shown at 500px wide on the page, serve a resized copy that is 500px wide, don't simply use CSS to scale it down to the right size. I have seen web sites attempting to send several multiple megabyte images to a client only to resize them using CSS or HTML attributes on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest pass the image name as parameter to GetImagePath
Try this:

```
public string GetImagePath(string imageName)
{
   return VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/images/" + imageName);
}
```

VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(string) converts a virtual path to an application absolute path.
So you will get something like "/images/yourimage.jpg".